# ROSARIA Linux Mint?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install ROSARIA in Linux Mint 13. I have the next error just after set the instructions "rosdep install ROSARIA". Its posible install ROSARIA in Linux Mint?

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ROSARIA: Unsupported OS [mint]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60651/rosaria-linux-mint?/) by [aslan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4678/aslan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep doesn't currently support mint.  You can [submit a pull request to add support](http://ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosdep/html/developers_guide.html)

In the mean time Mint has a 1-1 relationship to Ubuntu.  You should be able to follow the appropriate [Ubuntu Installation Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0